# Open access report from hyperlink?

Tags: ms-access

Could I send a hyperlink to a user via e-mail which when clicked will run and display an access report? Users will not have MS Access installed on their local machine but do have access to the local drive that the ".accdb" is stored on.

If yes; that's wonderful could you point me in a direction to get started.

If no; could you think of a workaround that might emulate this?

Goal: Allow for simple distribution of reports to new users who don't have access. Reports need to show updated information each time they're run (no redistribution required to get current data)

Comment: This is a rather open ended question and the answer is dependent on the tools/access you have available at your disposal.  You can do things like have the report output a PDF, attach it to an email and send it out or have it output to a folder in the network and send a link to the file path, etc.

Comment: Also they don't need to have the full version of Access installed.  The Access run-time is free, so short of installation time etc, there is no reason not to have it on the machine if they're consistently using the database.

Comment: The major tools available are MS Word and MS Excel. I will look into if it is possible to get Access run-time installed but unfortunately these computers are locked down and it was "fun" to try and get full access installed on one. 

Sending the report as an attachment wouldn't work for the data would be as old as the e-mail. I was hoping to find a way by using the fact that VBA is used in excel word and access to let them click a link that would use vba to get real data. The link could be to a word file or excel but simplicity would be key for the user.

Comment: There would need to be Access runtime or a PDF/some other format involved if you can't install it, for them to view the report.  You can have reports that get tossed into a network folder and then send a link to that file, so they can get the latest version of the report.  You can then manage the report validity on some sort of schedule.